# How to restrict content on a page in WordPress per user

Tags: wordpress, backend

I have a WordPress site with a customer login area. I want to be able to create a page with files to download for each individual customer - on one page all the files will be stored but only the customer that is currently logged in can view their files i.e. all other users files will not be viewable. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Would each customer have only one file or many files?

Comment: Yes I have but all the solutions I have found so far restrict whole pages rather than specific content, I don't want to have to create an individual page for each user as there could be hundreds of users. A customer could potentially have more than one file

Comment: At the moment is there something stored in a database to say a file belongs to a specific user?

Comment: No the files are uploaded through WordPress itself using a plugin. What I want is to be able to insert the file(s) into a page and restrict each file to a certain user.

Comment: But you will need to store in a database what user can see what file right?

Answer (score 0):

simply create a page after login with session then only the person having the coreect crentials can view your page and see the download link

Comment: The problem I see with this is that there could potentially be hundreds of unique users each with their own files so I am not sure this will work

Comment: you got your answers or still stucked?